# Picard group of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, algebraic-number-theory, projective-module

> I search for a simple proof for the fact that $\operatorname{Pic}(\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}])=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, where $\operatorname{Pic}(R)$ is the Picard group of the ring $R$ - the set of isomorphism classes of f.g. projective $R$-modules of of rank $1$.

I appreciate anybody cooperating!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For [Dedekind domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_domain) we have $\operatorname{Pic}(R)\simeq\operatorname{Cl}(R)$, where $\operatorname{Cl}(R)$ is the ideal class group of $R$. Your case is treated [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_class_group#Example_of_a_non-trivial_class_group) in detail.

Comment: For a more advanced approach using the Minkowski's bound you can have a look at these [lecture notes](http://cs-people.bu.edu/lapets/resource/icg.pdf).