# Is $\mathbb Z[\frac{1+\sqrt 5i}2]$ a ring of fractions of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 5i]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

> Does there exist a multiplicative set $S\subset \mathbb Z[\sqrt 5i]$ such that $\mathbb Z[\frac{1+\sqrt 5i}2]\cong S^{-1}\mathbb Z[\sqrt 5i]$?

Since the multiplicative structure of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 5i]$ is rather bizarre, I have few ideas how to attack it.

My first attempt: I find that it's sufficient to disprove it if one can show that $x^2+5y^2=2^n$ has no integer solution. But I cannot prove this statement either.

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/194719/242) for further references, and [see here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=156438) for a handful of Math Reviiews of related papers.\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is a Dedekind domain with torsion class group, and for these rings *every* overring, that is, every ring containing it and contained in its field of fractions, is a ring of fractions.

For more details I recommend you [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1964-110-02/S0002-9947-1964-0156868-2/S0002-9947-1964-0156868-2.pdf), especially Theorem 2, and [this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1067769/picard-group-of-mathbb-z-sqrt-5).

Answer (score 1):

Let $\delta=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}i}{2}$, then $\bar{\delta}=1-\delta$, and $\delta(1-\delta)=\frac{3}{2}$. Then $\delta(1-\delta)-1=\frac{1}{2}$. If $S$ is $\{2^n:n\ge 0\}$, then $S^{-1}\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}i] \subset \mathbb{Z}[\delta]$, and since $\mathbb{Z}[\delta]\subset S^{-1}\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}i]$ it is in fact a ring of fractions.